# Redirect image filepath to external URL in Apache

Tags: apache, redirect

I'm trying to redirect requests for an image folder to an external URL (AWS Cloudfront).

I have this in my Virtual Host config:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/images/social_media/$ https://cdn.<domain_name>.com/images/social_media/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

However, it's not giving me the image name I'm requesting, and throwing a 403 Forbidden. How can I give it a wildcard to redirect all image requests to the external URL?

I have also tried:

```
^/images/social_media/\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$ https://cdn.<domain_name>.com/images/social_media/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

With that one I get no 403. It just doesn't redirect at all.

I just want any requests to the images in that folder to redirect to the new external URL.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: One thing I don't understand is why `^images` worked, but not `^/images`. I believe the accepted answer would show what would fix it, and explain why, and I don't have the 'why'.....yet.

I went with .htaccess and this is working:

```
RewriteRule ^images/social_media/(.*)$ https://cdn.<domain_name>.com/images/social_media/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```